# S-Video to USB converter with macos sdk available?

Tags: macos, video, sdk, usb, video-capture

Im looking for a S-Video to USB converter which comes with a macosx sdk.

To give a tip of what im looking for [Elgato video converter](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/Video-Capture/product1.en.html). However, since it brings no sdk, im not enable to develop software managing the video capture data.

Does anyone know a similar product with a SDK?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll be hard pressed to find something like this that isn't extremely expensive. S-Video to USB isn't a "converter" it will be a USB video card which is already rare enough. Finding one that offers the SDK is going to be extremely unlikely.

Comment: Do you suggest something @SpencerRuport ? I don't know how hard is to manipulate VLC... Maybe easier to find support right?

Comment: If I were you I would contact Elgato and ask if they have any plans to develop an SDK. Or any other company that provides a similar product.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the Sensoray 2253:

http://www.sensoray.com/products/2253.htm

They have an SDK for Linux and Windows.  (Sorry, none for Mac OS.)  I have heard that their customer support is good. (And yes, their products are expensive, but not bad considering the quality of support, from what I hear.)

Another alternative to the Sensoray board: “The Imaging Source.” They offer an SDK for their converter, and it allows uncompressed video, too.

http://www.theimagingsource.com/en_US/topics/usb-video-adapters/

(Update) This product is no longer being manufactured.

Finally, VisioForge offers and SDK for generic TV tuners, which are fairly cheap.

(I've hit my URL limit. Google it!)

I don't have any experience with this product, however.  And the single-seat price is about $180.

Answer (score 1):

Just as contribution for the community I'll post here what solutio we've found as the best one.
We have acquired an EasyCap device with STK1160 Chipset and we are extending the [EasyCapViewer](http://bentrask.com/easycap/) driver for our purposes.
It sounded like a cheap and working good solution for us. The video works in every macos systems we have tested: from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion!